# Handling ID's in has_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm making a program to control tv shows, so my relationships are: `Show` has many `Seasons` and a `Season` has many `Episodes`.

I didn't knew how to pass the `show.id` for the table of seasons, and a friend of mine helped but I didn't understood his method. And when I've tried to use the same method for passing `season_id` for episodes but I can't. So here is the code:

**season controller**

```
def create
  @season = Season.new(season_params)
  if session[:id] != nil
  @season.show_id = (session[:id])
  session[:id] = nil
end
```

**Show view of Show**(I choose a bad name to work).
In this view I want to see all the seasons and episodes related to that show.

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
<% @seasons = Season.all %>

<% @seasons.where(:show_id => @show.id).each do |season| %>
<tr>
  <td><%= season.order %></td>
  <td><%= season.status %></td>
</tr>
<% end %>
<%= link_to 'create seasons', season_new_path(@show.id) %>
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_show_path(@show) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', shows_path %>
```

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
resources :episodes
resources :seasons
resources :shows
get 'seasons/create/:id' => 'seasons#new', as: :season_new
```

Is there a better way to pass the id's of `show.id` for `season` and `season.id` for episode?

I forgot to push the code that I wrote for episode and its in another pc.

If you want see more of the code check my github: [Github code](https://github.com/tdunky/Javi)

Comment: you can try using `accepts_nested_attributes_for method`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `accepts_nested_attributes_for :seasons` in `Show` model

new.html.erb, should look like this

```
<% form_for @show do |f| %>
    <%= f.error_messages %>
    <% f.fields_for :seasons do |s| %>
        <p>
            <%= s.label :order, "Order" %><br />
            <%= s.text_field :order %>
        </p>
        <p>
            <%= s.label :status, "Status" %><br />
            <%= s.text_field :status %>
        </p>
    <% end %>
    <p><%= f.submit "Submit" %></p>
<% end %>
```

show.html.erb

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<% for season in @show.seasons %>
     <td><%= season.order %></td>
     <td><%= season.status %></td>
<% end %>

<%= link_to 'create seasons', season_new_path(@show) %>
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_show_path(@show) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', shows_path %>
```

Comment: great, i didn't knew this accepts_nested_attributes_for. But if i also want to show the episodes of each season i can't use accepts_nested_attributes_for :episodes in the show model. or i can use accepts_nested_attributes_for :episodes in season model, and use @show.seasons.episodes?

Comment: sorry for the number of questions , i'm a little lost in the beginning of rails, that new.html.erb, is the view from season? because i already have a new.html.erb for show, that create the shows. so if its in season view, how i know that the  id of that @show is the same after i click on create show. don't know if i was clear.